# Computer says "succeed to download nbp file" but doesn't boot into PE

Tags: windows-7, boot, pxe

I'm trying install windows 7 over network. I tried tftpd and serva, but with both of them, my laptop will just get to the message "succeed to download nbp file" and then proceeds to boot normally instead of booting into PE

this is on a Toshiba Satellia L50-a

Answer (score 1):

Serva 2.X requires to boot UEFI devices in Legacy Mode.
If not the transferred NBP (Network Boot Program) will fail to run and 
the boot process will continue with the next option available in the boot chain.

If your Toshiba is an UEFI PC then try booting in Legacy Mode

EDIT:
Now Serva 3.X supports UEFI and you should be able to correctly boot into UEFI mode. If your particular firmware is not fully conformant to the UEFI standard you can try switching Serva Boot Manger Mode from 1 (default) to 2 or 3.

Comment: Damn, that's what I was trying to avoid. If I boot in legacy mode, then I can't install to a gpt partitioned drive, which I currently have Ubuntu installed on

Comment: you are right no gpt when booting in Legacy mode. At least try to boot in legacy mode and see if your PXE problem is solved.

Comment: it worked in legacy mode

Comment: Then that answers your question.

Comment: Pat, I've tried everything. Is there anyway I'll be able to install windows on this GPT drive?

Comment: You have to wait for Serva 3.0, Sorry :-(

Comment: Apparently we need to buy the pro edition to support UEFI booting to WinPE.